# Stored procedure called from Powershell does not execute via SMO object

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure from a Powershell terminal by using the following code, but the procedure does not seem to execute and there is no error thrown in the terminal.

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
$so = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -argumentList 'PC-1001'
$db = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database($so, "TestDB")
$sproc = $db.StoredProcedures.Item("dproc")
$sproc.Execute
```

The supporting SQL code is:

```
create table dummytable (id int identity(1,1), ranwhen datetime default getdate(), dummyval varchar(10));

create procedure dproc as
begin
set nocount on
    insert into dummytable (dummyval)
    select char(datepart(hour, getdate()) * datepart(minute, getdate()) * datepart(second, getdate()) % 256)
end
```

If I execute the procedure in SSMS (`exec dproc`) it works (data is inserted into the table).

Any ideas why it's not working from Powershell? (no data is being inserted into the dummy table)

Update:

I've changed the declaration of the `$db` and `$sproc` variable to:

```
$db = $so.Databases.Item("TestDB")
$sproc = $db.StoredProcedures.Item("dproc")
```

And when checking the contents of the `$sproc` object, I can see that every property is correct (T-SQL code is there, URN value is correct and references the correct DB and schema).

Comment: Try to add bracets to execute method, like this $sproc.Execute()

Comment: Have you tried with also specifying the schema? Like $sproc = $db.StoredProcedures.Item("dproc", "dbo") -- or whatever schema it is

Comment: @KirillPashkov It throws an error: "Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.StoredProcedure] does not contain a method named 'Execute'."

Comment: When you run this you see nothing at all returned in the console, right? `$sproc.Execute`. If it were a method you would need to have `$proc.Execute()`. The trouble is, none of the documentation for the class suggests what your'e attempting is even possible.

Comment: @EduardUta When checking the contents of the `$sproc` variable it says under URN: "Urn: Server[@Name='PC-1001']/Database[@Name='TestDB']/StoredProcedure[@Name='dproc' and @Schema='dbo']

Comment: @ChrisDent I'm looking into the `dummyTable`, I'm not expecting anything to be returned to the terminal

Comment: Yes, but in PowerShell `$sproc.Execute` is a Property reference. Without some clever wiring that simply will not do anything other than display something. Methods affect change, but those require () on the end. There is no such method exposed on this class. To verify there is no such property either run `$sproc | Get-Member` and review the list.

Comment: @ChrisDent Hmm, you're right, there is no `Execute` method there, not even a property. Curious why it's not throwing a syntax error, I was expecting it to do so..

Comment: Unless you turn on Strict Mode PowerShell does not validate whether or not properties exist. It simply returns `$null`. A feature of the language if you like. C# / VB would have been much less forgiving.

Comment: @ChrisDent Thank you for the info, do you happen to have an alternative to what I'm trying to do? (I'd be very grateful, plus points here on SO if you post an answer =) )

Comment: Have you tried `$sproc.ExecuteNonQuery()`?

Comment: @gofr1 Based on the results of `$sproc | Get-Member`, there is no `ExecuteNonQuery` method associated to this type of object.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I am using `System.Data.SqlClient` to interact with db, and `ExecuteNonQuery` works there, that is why I searched MSDN and found, that this method could be used via SMO ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.executenonquery.aspx)), that is why I suggest you to try it.

Comment: @gofr1 Strangely enough, `ExecuteNonQuery` does not work as it returns an error: `Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "1" argument(s): "ExecuteNonQuery failed for Database 'TestDB'`, but `ExecuteWithResults` works as expected, but with the added overhead of returning an empty response.

Answer (score 3):

The StoredProcedure class does not provide a means of executing the stored procedure it represents.

You might try, and I have taken no steps to validate this is possible, using:

```
$so.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("dproc")
```

Failing that, you might simply fall back to using System.Data.SqlClient.

Comment: `$so.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("dproc")` does not work, but I'll look into `Data.SqlClient`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use System.Data.SqlClient as well. I used to run stored procedures like this:

```
$SQL = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$ConnectionStrig = "Server=localhost;Database=testtaskdb;Integrated Security=True;"
$SQL.ConnectionString = $ConnectionStrig
$SQL.Open()
$CMD = $SQL.CreateCommand()
$CMD.CommandText = "exec myproc"

#if you need to just run the stored procedure
$null=$CMD.ExecuteReader()

#if you need to get the output
$Table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$Table.Load($CMD.ExecuteReader())
Write-Output $Table
```